# How to retrieve director_name and director_image here in supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase

```
Director (id,director_name,director_image)

movies (id,movie_name,movie_description)

movie_director(director_id,movie_id) // movie_id and director_id are the foreign key.

 const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('movie_director')
        .select(`
          director_id,
          Director:director_id(director_name)
        `)
        .eq('movie_id', 3); // This query is not able to retrieve director_name and director_image
```

I expected to retrieve director_name and director_image to show up but nothing did.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query that joins the Director table with the movie_director table using the director_id:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('movie_director')
  .select(`
    director_id,
    Director:director_id (
      director_name,
      director_image
    )
  `)
  .eq('movie_id', 3);
```

This part of the query is Supabase specific:

```
Director:director_id (
  director_name,
  director_image
)
```

It represents a join operation with the Director table using the director_id